# DNS 'Accidentally' Uninstalled in AD Domain - Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

So, I did something quite foolish (it's a long story) and accidentally started an uninstall of DNS on one of my domain controllers. Fortunately, my Active Directory appears to be functioning properly, and the uninstall seems to be pending completion until reboot.

The DNS Manager console is still active on the DC in question. I only have one conditional forwarder configured and a few forward lookup zones that are external to my AD domain. These all still appear in the console, and all resolve properly when queried.

%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\dns on the DC in question does not contain any .dns files specific to my domain and the 'mydomain'.dns file on my other DC does not contain any of these external forward lookup zones-- also, the other DC's DNS Management console also contains all of my zones.

So it seems that all of this info is stored in Active Directory (all as integrated zones) instead of .dns files, and therefore things are not so bad. Is this correct?

Also, is there anything I might need to look out for when rebooting the server and reinstalling DNS (other that possibly having to reconfigure my conditional forwarder)?

Comment: Thanks. I'm tentatively hopeful about this, just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything major that I was missing (aside from the fact that I need to find less stressful ways of learning new things). I'll check back in tonight and post an update.

Comment: Everything went fine. My conditional forwarder was also preserved. Note to future self: next time you want to learn whether you can do something like uninstall DNS without affecting AD, *DON'T* check by clicking through the uninstall dialogues. And if you're foolish enough to do that, make damn sure you click 'Cancel' and not 'Next' by accident.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the zones in question are Active-Directory integrated and hosted on at least one other server, judging by the fact that they're still resolving.

If you have other AD controllers running DNS, this is almost guaranteed to be the case; meaning that you've lost nothing and can reinstall with no issue (just reconfigure your forwarders and such).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have at least one other AD controller with DNS, it'll have all the necessary information/configuration (it would be insane to only have one AD/DNS server after all). Just reboot the server, note this might take a long time, add the DNS server role again, then recreate the Domain as a AD Integrated; it should pickup all the necessary settings from AD.